# Telemetry issue using Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, telemetry

I am attempting to start a new Gatsby project, but keep running into a Telemetry issue I am unable to figure out how to fix.
I have installed `gatsby-cli` globally but every time I try run any `gatsby` command on my cli, I will get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\gatsby-telemetry\lib\telemetry.js:39
  store = new _eventStorage.EventStorage();
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\gatsby-telemetry\lib\index.js:21:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
```

I am on Windows 10, I have uninstalled and re-installed Gatsby, I have changed Node versions...
Have spoken to a few people and seems like my local environment specific problem, but I have run out of ideas.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: @FerranBuireu  I tried a few different versions. Currently on the latest, but also tried 12 and 14.

Answer (score 0):

Update!

I have fixed the issue by uninstalling `Nodist`.
Seems that I had installed `Node` through nvm as well as direct from the NodeJS site, meaning I had two different node environments in my local dev setup, which was confusing Gatsby.

Comment: how did you do this?